# Cannot deploy Spring Boot container to apt-get installed Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, apt

I want to deploy a Spring Boot war file to a Tomcat server that was installed via apt-get. The war file is supposed to handle some REST calls coming from a front end.

The application already runs well in my IDE, as a standalone jar file, and on Tomcat servers that were installed by unpacking the binaries from the Apache Tomcat homepage.

I have tried to deploy the war to Tomcat 7 and 8, which were installed via apt-get, but both times it did not work. The war file seems to get loaded correctly by Tomcat, since there are no errors in the log files and the folder for the war file is created in /webapps. But whenever I try to access/call the endpoints of the application I get a 404 error.

Is there any difference between a Tomcat server that was installed by unpacking the binaries and one that was installed via apt-get that might cause a Spring Boot war file to stop working?

This is what my Spring Boot configuration class looks like:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

}
```

And here is the gradle file for the application:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = "Spring snapshot"
        url = "http://repo.springsource.org/snapshot"
    }
    maven {
        name = 'Spring milestone'
        url = "http://repo.springsource.org/milestone"
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.2.RELEASE")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

war {
    baseName = 'project'
}

bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'packagepath.Application'
}

configurations{
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    //Spring
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.2.RELEASE'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.2.2.RELEASE'
}

springBoot {
}
```

Comment: Are you using the correct URL?

Comment: I think so. It is the same one I use when deployed on the binary Tomcat, which is ip:port/project/endpointname.

Comment: instead of `project` it generally is `name-of-war` and not your project.

Comment: I know. I just called it project because that's what I put as the baseName in the build.gradle. So the war file would be called project.war

Comment: Did you try renaming to ROOT.war and deploying?

Comment: Tried it a couple of seconds ago. Both ip:port/endpointname and ip:port/ROOT/endpointname get the same 404 Error. Lowercased ROOT in the url doesn't work either.

Comment: That's odd. You don't accidentally have a web.xml?

Comment: No. Not in my project and not in the loaded war file.